# Should I save user's profile Image in Session Storage to avoid multiple server calls?

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, chat

I have a chat in my app that currently is fetching the user profile image every time a new message is shown.
I would like to store this image somewhere so it wont do so many server calls.
Current code example:

```
   <div *ngFor="let message of messages[chatID]" class="mb-3">
          <img [src]="message.image>
   </div>
```

Comment: you can base64 the image and put it in localstorage

Comment: I don't think this is necessary, If you inspect the network tab, on subsequent reloads of the page, you will probably get a 304, which means it has used a cache of the last time that call was made.